# What items can a player teleport into the Goblins vs. Gnomes board?

Tags: hearthstone

Hearthstone has a variety of themed game boards. Each board features various interactive components and Easter Eggs. Among other things the Goblins vs. Gnomes board features a teleportation chamber that seems to be controlled by the position of the levers to the left of the chamber. Does the position of the levers effect the items which will be teleported? What items can a player teleport into the chamber?

[image: Goblins vs. Gnomes board with teleportation chamber circled]

Comment: Definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [What objects are interactive on the playing board?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/139148)

> **Goblins vs. gnomes board**
>
> - Switches and red button on teleporter - pressing red button will spawn vegetable,fish,boot,diamond,bomb,banana,kite or chicken-bot
>     inside teleporter.Setting of switches doesn't appear to matter.